How can I prove that if $f:[0,+\infty)\to[0,1]$ is continuous and increasing, then it is uniformly continuous?
The problem is the following:
Let $f:[0,+\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that it is continuous, strictly growing and its image is contained in $[0,1]$, is uniformly continuous.
I've tried in several ways but none of them convinces me because I can never get to use all hypothesis. I want to know how can I write the solution to this problem in an understandable (and correct) way.

Your conditions are contradictory. If $f$ takes the value $1$ at some point $x_0$ (which it should, as $1$ is in its image), then what would $f(x_0+1)$ be? It must be bigger than $1$, which is impossible.

You're right, it must say that the image is contained in $[0,1]$, let me correct it

You say that you've tried - you should write out whatever your best effort at solving this is.

Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question + please avoid "no clue" questions: you are not showing any work.
Moreover, your post is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2096080

I mean I know, but every thing I've tried has failed. e.g. using successions or trying to prove it was Lipschitz. I was really like 2 hours trying to solve the exercise, I just didn't wanna post all my nonsense tries

@Anne Bauva thank you for pointing this out, deleted my previous comment.

Let $y_0=lim_{x\to\infty}f(x).$ Let $\epsilon>0.$ Pice $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=y_0-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}).$ Then $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,x_0+1]$ and for any $x,y\geq x_0$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2}.$ Thus $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty).$
Leaving a few details for the interested reader.

This answer duplicates the answer of the linked post, which is more detailed. This duplicate post was reported in a comment above, 35 min before.

Sorry didn’t see the relevant link.

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.
